# What is most efficient HTML5 Canvas Rotation method?

Tags: html, rotation, html5-canvas

I want to know what is the most efficient way to rotate a specific image on the canvas.

## 1

```
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.rotate(rect.radians);
        context.strokeRect(-rect.width/2,  -rect.height/2, rect.width,  rect.height);
        context.rotate(rect.radians *-1);
        context.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
```

## 2

```
        context.save();
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.rotate(rect.radians);
        context.strokeRect(-rect.width/2,  -rect.height/2, rect.width, rect.height);
        context.restore();
```

## 3

```
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.rotate(rect.radians);
        context.strokeRect(-rect.width/2,  -rect.height/2, rect.width, rect.height);
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

I will be running this function with multiple objects every animation frame.

Comment: Why not run the tests yourselves at http://jsperf.com/ or you wanted us to run the tests *for* you? .-)

Comment: @Abdias, no I did not mean it in that way, I'm just quite ignorant of how the Canvas API works, so I asked hoping someone understood the better method from my examplse.

Comment: It depends on several factors such as browser implementation. But I would put my bet on option 3...

Answer (score 0):

Option#2 is definitely out as most efficient because it resets all the context's state properties, not just the transform matrix.

@Ken-AbdiasSoftware is probably right about #3--directly reset with the identity matrix.

**Of course, the most efficient rotation could be not doing any rotation at all.**

If your image(s) rotate to pre-defined angles, you could cache the image at those angles and then use drawImage without the need for transforms at all.

If you have seldom/never rotated components, group them on a separate canvas/image from the often rotated components.